# cron job on php script having curl request

Tags: php, curl, cron, wget

I am using an api (for sending sms) for which I am using curl request in my custom function in a controller. we are calling this api using cron job by calling custom function (I am using currently wget for this).

When cron runs it hits that API multiple times and users get same sms multiple times.

And when I run that url (custom function url) manually in browser then user gets sms only once.

Cron runs one time in a day

Cron code :

```
5 18 * * * wget -O - https://www.siteurl.com/sms_notifications/seller
```

Php script :

```
<?php
 $url="http://api.textlocal.in/send/";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
        ));
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_errno($ch)) {
            //echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
            return false;
        } else {
            curl_close($ch);
          $this->JobsModel->updateSMSNotificationStatus($smsnotificationid,'yes');
            return true;
        }
?>
```

Is this issue because I have used wget and do I need to switch to curl or php and why.

Comment: Very unclear. Do you call the same script in cron and in browser? How often runs the script? Each minute? How do you update data? And so on...

Comment: You really need to provide more information. Like how is the call in cron set up?

Comment: try `wget` parameters like `--tries=1`